# CakePHP - Store a cache in a database and use it with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cakephp, caching

With CakePHP, I want to cache content of variables and store it in a database.

I also want to fetch this cache with Javascript (and with CakePHP).

What kind of solutions can I use ?

***Edit*** : to be more specific, I calculate statistitcs with CakePHP and so as to don't calculate it every time, I would like to cache results. I have another application developped with PhoneGap that would do the same thing. The ideal thing would be to have a single cache, stored in a database, and each application would use this cache in the database.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Maybe give a small example on what do you want to do

Comment: OK to be more specific with my previous question, is there some kind of table schema, that demonstrates what kind of data are stored? Your question is still very general.

Comment: In fact, there are lots of statistics to calculate with many tables, but all of this staticts are numbers.  
To give an example, imagine that I have a table **statistics** with 4 fields: '*id*', '*start_period*', '*end_period*', '*cache*'; and another table **numbers** with 4 fields : '*id*', '*period*', '*turnover*', '*quantity*'. In '*cache*' I would *store* the sum of turnover, the maximum of turnover, the sum of quantity, the maximum of quantity, the mean of quantity for data in the given period.

Is it clear? Do you want some more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could store all the statistical data in an `array()` format like that:

```
array(
    'sum' => $sum_value,
    'max' => $max_value,
    ...
)
```

After that you could simple `json_encode()` the above array and save it in the `cache` field,
using a convinient `save` method. When retrieving the `cache` field you can simply `json_decode()` the data and you have your array back ready for modification and update.

As for the javascript, I believe you want to use AJAX functionality. You can retrieve, store and update your `cache` field using AJAX very easily. The [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) is quite explainable about handling AJAX requests.

I hope this helps